# How to display form in a dialog window?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a simple form consisting of 3 text fields and a cancel/ok button. This is in a GroupLayout. I'd like to know how to make this form pop up in a new window similar to a dialog? Can I pass my GroupLayout to a JDialog? I also need to validate the input before the form window closes. I currently have this working but it uses a new frame to do so and I've read that this is not the way to do it so I am asking here.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.*;

public class AddStockPromptTest {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JPanel formPanel;
    private JPanel buttonPanel;
    //private GroupLayout layout;
    private JLabel lblItem;
    private JLabel lblPrice;
    private JLabel lblQuantity;
    private JTextField itemField;
    private JTextField priceField;
    private JTextField quantityField;
    private JButton okBtn;
    private JButton cancelBtn;

    public AddStockPromptTest() {
        frame = new JFrame("Add New Stock Item");
        //Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();

        mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        formPanel = new JPanel();

        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(formPanel);
        formPanel.setLayout(groupLayout);
        groupLayout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);

        lblItem = new JLabel("Item:");
        lblPrice = new JLabel("Price:");
        lblQuantity = new JLabel("Quantity:");

        itemField = new JTextField();
        priceField = new JTextField();
        quantityField = new JTextField();

        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup()
                        .addComponent(lblItem)
                        .addComponent(lblPrice)
                        .addComponent(lblQuantity))
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup()
                        .addComponent(itemField)
                        .addComponent(priceField)
                        .addComponent(quantityField))
        );

        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(lblItem)
                        .addComponent(itemField))
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(lblPrice)
                        .addComponent(priceField))
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(lblQuantity)
                        .addComponent(quantityField))
        );


        cancelBtn = new JButton("Cancel");
        buttonPanel.add(cancelBtn);

        okBtn = new JButton("OK");
        buttonPanel.add(okBtn);


        mainPanel.add(formPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.add(mainPanel);


        frame.setTitle("Basil's Pizza Ordering System");
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //addStockPrompt();
    }

    private void addStockPrompt() {

    }

}
```

Comment: *"I'd like to know how to make this form pop up in a new window similar to a dialog?"* Use a `JDialog` or `JOptionPane` ..

Comment: See example #7 [**here**](https://www.mkyong.com/swing/java-swing-joptionpane-showinputdialog-example/).

Comment: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,formPanel,"Form",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);`

Answer (score 0):

JOptionPane will give you a dialog box. Use this in actionperformed event of your okay button.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
```